# Python interpreter doesn't read json

Tags: python, json

My goal is to get an input of JSON and output it to InfluxDB. Since I'm gathering data from a pfSense, my tools are limited. Therefore I'm using Python 3.8.

Developing on a Debian Machine first I wrote this code:

```py
#!/usr/local/bin/python3.8
import os
import json
from influxdb import InfluxDBClient
from datetime import datetime

INTERFACES = ["igb0", "pppoe0"]
WORKING_FOLDER = "/tmp/json"
NOW = datetime.now()
CLIENT = InfluxDBClient("host", "8086", "user", "pw", "firewall")
for interface in INTERFACES:
    stats = {}
    os.popen(
        "vnstat --json d 2 -i {} > {}/{}_d.json".format(interface, WORKING_FOLDER, interface)
    ).read()
    os.popen(
        "vnstat --json m 2 -i {} > {}/{}_m.json".format(interface, WORKING_FOLDER, interface)
    ).read()

    with open(f"{WORKING_FOLDER}/{interface}_d.json", "r") as j:
        day = json.loads(j.read())
    with open(f"{WORKING_FOLDER}/{interface}_m.json", "r") as k:
        month = json.loads(k.read())

    if not len(day["interfaces"][0]["traffic"]["day"]) == 2:
        stats["yesterday"] = {"rx": 0, "tx": 0}
        stats["today"] = {
            "rx": day["interfaces"][0]["traffic"]["day"][0]["rx"],
            "tx": day["interfaces"][0]["traffic"]["day"][0]["tx"],
        }

    else:
        stats["yesterday"] = {
            "rx": day["interfaces"][0]["traffic"]["day"][0]["rx"],
            "tx": day["interfaces"][0]["traffic"]["day"][0]["tx"],
        }
        stats["today"] = {
            "rx": day["interfaces"][0]["traffic"]["day"][1]["rx"],
            "tx": day["interfaces"][0]["traffic"]["day"][1]["tx"],
        }

    if not len(month["interfaces"][0]["traffic"]["month"]) == 2:
        stats["last_month"] = {"rx": 0, "tx": 0}
        stats["this_month"] = {
            "rx": month["interfaces"][0]["traffic"]["month"][0]["rx"],
            "tx": month["interfaces"][0]["traffic"]["month"][0]["tx"],
        }

    else:
        stats["last_month"] = {
            "rx": month["interfaces"][0]["traffic"]["month"][0]["rx"],
            "tx": month["interfaces"][0]["traffic"]["month"][0]["tx"],
        }
        stats["this_month"] = {
            "rx": month["interfaces"][0]["traffic"]["month"][1]["rx"],
            "tx": month["interfaces"][0]["traffic"]["month"][1]["tx"],
        }

    json_body = [
        {
            "measurement": f"stats_{interface}",
            "time": NOW,
            "fields": {
                "yesterday_rx": stats["yesterday"]["rx"],
                "yesterday_tx": stats["yesterday"]["tx"],
                "yesterday_total": int(stats["yesterday"]["rx"]) + int(stats["yesterday"]["tx"]),
                "today_rx": stats["today"]["rx"],
                "today_tx": stats["today"]["tx"],
                "today_total": int(stats["today"]["rx"]) + int(stats["today"]["tx"]),
                "last_month_rx": stats["last_month"]["rx"],
                "last_month_tx": stats["last_month"]["tx"],
                "last_month_total": int(stats["last_month"]["rx"]) + int(stats["last_month"]["tx"]),
                "this_month_rx": stats["this_month"]["rx"],
                "this_month_tx": stats["this_month"]["tx"],
                "this_month_total": int(stats["this_month"]["rx"]) + int(stats["this_month"]["tx"]),
            },
        }
    ]

    CLIENT.write_points(json_body)
```

Testing it on my Debian machine (with line 12 & 13 commented out to not overwrite my JSON files) everything works like a charm. So I moved the script to my pfSense and I'm getting the following error:

```
[2.5.2-RELEASE][admin@pfSense]/usr/local/pythonscripts: ./trafficstats.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./trafficstats.py", line 18, in <module>
    month = json.loads(k.read())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

And I'm asking myself why. Because looking at the moth file is a valid JSON if I see it correctly:

```json
{"vnstatversion":"2.7","jsonversion":"2","interfaces":[{"name":"igb0","alias":"WAN","created":{"date":{"year":2022,"month":2,"day":4}},"updated":{"date":{"year":2022,"month":2,"day":12},"time":{"hour":9,"minute":30}},"traffic":{"total":{"rx":82416467756,"tx":43825701833},"month":[{"id":88,"date":{"year":2022,"month":2},"rx":82416467756,"tx":43825701833}]}}]}
```

Does anybody know why I'm getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Expecting value at char 0" generally means that you're trying to `json.loads()` an empty string:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads("")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python39\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

You're not checking whether those `vnstat` invocations succeed (you should be using `subprocess.check_call()` instead of `os.popen` anyway since you're not really even using pipes), so it's likely the files have been created but are empty.

All in all, I'd maybe refactor things to something like this:

- use `subprocess.check_call()` to wait for the process to finish (and check result)
- don't use a `stats` dict that's basically just thrown away
- refactor repetitive bits

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3.8
import json
import subprocess
from datetime import datetime

from influxdb import InfluxDBClient

INTERFACES = ["igb0", "pppoe0"]
WORKING_FOLDER = "/tmp/json"
NOW = datetime.now()
CLIENT = InfluxDBClient("host", "8086", "user", "pw", "firewall")


# Process an interfaces.X.traffic.PERIOD dict into a pair of (previous_rx, previous_tx), (current_rx, current_tx)
def process_traffic(traffic):
    if len(traffic) != 2:
        return ((0, 0), (traffic[0]["rx"], traffic[0]["tx"]))
    return ((traffic[0]["rx"], traffic[0]["tx"]), (traffic[1]["rx"], traffic[1]["tx"]))


def process_iface(interface):
    day_json = f"{WORKING_FOLDER}/{interface}_d.json"
    month_json = f"{WORKING_FOLDER}/{interface}_m.json"
    # TODO: consider shlex.quote for safety
    subprocess.check_call(
        f"vnstat --json d 2 -i {interface} > {day_json}",
        shell=True,
    )
    subprocess.check_call(
        f"vnstat --json m 2 -i {interface} > {month_json}",
        shell=True,
    )

    with open(day_json, "r") as j:
        day_data = json.loads(j.read())
    with open(month_json, "r") as k:
        month_data = json.loads(k.read())

    (yesterday_rx, yesterday_tx), (today_rx, today_tx) = process_traffic(
        day_data["interfaces"][0]["traffic"]["day"]
    )
    (last_month_rx, last_month_tx), (this_month_rx, this_month_tx) = process_traffic(
        month_data["interfaces"][0]["traffic"]["month"]
    )

    json_body = [
        {
            "measurement": f"stats_{interface}",
            "time": NOW,
            "fields": {
                "yesterday_rx": yesterday_rx,
                "yesterday_tx": yesterday_tx,
                "yesterday_total": int(yesterday_rx) + int(yesterday_tx),
                "today_rx": today_rx,
                "today_tx": today_tx,
                "today_total": int(today_rx) + int(today_tx),
                "last_month_rx": last_month_rx,
                "last_month_tx": last_month_tx,
                "last_month_total": int(last_month_rx) + int(last_month_tx),
                "this_month_rx": this_month_rx,
                "this_month_tx": this_month_tx,
                "this_month_total": int(this_month_rx) + int(this_month_tx),
            },
        }
    ]

    CLIENT.write_points(json_body)


def main():
    for interface in INTERFACES:
        process_iface(interface)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: That is my problem, the File is NOT empty. my cat output I put in my answer ist the json file that was generated. Thats why I'm so suprised. The file is there, it is an valid json, so why won't it be loaded.

Regards your recommendation: I'll have a look into that, sounds like this will be better

Comment: Well, another thing is you're using `popen`; the subprocess is still running while you're starting to read the file. ;-) A `cat` run afterwards will see the finished file.

Comment: Please see my edit for a refactor ✨

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much for that. I'm a beginner in Python so I need some time to understand what is going on there, but my test worked :) 

So thank you very much for that!